# Delphi compiler error E2064 left side cannot be assigned to

Tags: delphi, unicode, c++builder, delphi-xe

I inherited a Delphi application and I know nothing about object pascal.

*It's a BPL that I need to compile into the new version of C++ Builder XE*.
When I run a make I get the error:

E2064 left side cannot be assigned to.

I've learned enough obj pascal to know I have a constant that is trying to be assigned a value.

But, apparently, you can over ride this behanvior; essentially turning constants into vars by going into Build options under the Delphi compiler and turning on "Assignable Typed constants".

I did that and I continue to get the same error.

I tried surrounding my code with {$J+} and {$J-} and still it will not compile.

```
procedure TChunkIDAT.CopyInterlacedRGB8(const Pass: Byte;
  Src, Dest, Trans{$IFDEF Store16bits}, Extra{$ENDIF}: pChar );
var
  Col: Integer;
 begin
 {Get first column and enter in loop}
 Col := ColumnStart[Pass];
 Dest := pChar(Longint(Dest) + Col * 3);
 repeat
 {Copy this row}

  Byte(Dest^) := fOwner.GammaTable[pByte(Longint(Src) + 2)^]; inc(Dest);
```

Get the error on last line.  If I change the const to a var, I then get the error that the declaration differs from the previous declaration but I have no idea where the previous declaration is....

Comment: @jachguate target is XE, so it looks like a Unicode issue.

Comment: I hadn't realized my 38% rate.  Thanks for pointing that out, I'll see if I can fix that.  It's a package I did not write (3rd party from IOCOMP.com).  And it's a 3rd party set of VCL controls used in C++ Builder 6 I'm trying to just compile for CBuilder XE as they don't yet have an XE version of their tools out yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're type-casting a two-byte thing (`Char`) into a one-byte thing (`Byte`). *Reading* that value is easy to define, but making that value *writable* is tricky, probably for the same reason the types of formal and actual "var" parameters need to be identical.

Maybe you wanted to type-cast it to a two-byte thing, such as `Word`. Or maybe you want `GammaTable` to be an array of `Char` so you don't have to type-cast at all. Or maybe, if this code was originally written for a Delphi version earlier than 2009, you want those `PChar` declarations to be `PAnsiChar` — character types have gotten wider. Another option is to type-cast `Dest` to `PByte`, and *then* dereference the result. That's probably a bad idea, though, because you'll only be overwriting every other byte of the buffer.

Based on the name of the function, it sounds like `PChar` was never the right data type to use. That type is for *character* data, but I think this code is dealing with *bytes*. The correct thing to do is probably to change `PChar` to `PByte`, and then you don't need to type-cast `Dest` at all.

The `$J` directive is irrelevant; it controls whether the compiler will allow you to assign values to typed constants. You don't have any of those in this code.

Comment: This is some pretty bad code.  I'm going to guess the compiler used to tolerate casts on the left side of the equals but doesn't anymore.  It never would have occurred to me that it would be tolerated--as a programmer I sure wouldn't have tolerated it.  I know they have closed up a few other cases of things that weren't supposed to compile but did, maybe this is another.

Comment: The compiler should still tolerate left-side casts, @Loren. It can be useful sometimes, such as when you want to assign the value of an interface variable without triggering reference counting — just type-cast the target to `Pointer`. The issue here is that as of Delphi 2009, the sizes are different.

Comment: To recap:  (1) bad code?  I didn't write (2) I don't know object pascal what so ever (3) it's a 3rd party vcl control from IOCOMP that apparently does not support BuilderXE yet and I'm simply trying to compile the Design time package against the run-time images under BuilderXE and not knowing pascal is presenting a challenge to me.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I substituted all PChars for PBytes and I can now get past the errors and get this sucker to compile and link.  However, when I attempt to install the resulting BPL I get IOCOMP65 contains unit Pnglang which is also in package vclimg150.  Investigating the comments above, I looked to comment out the pngimage but I can't find where it's included.  Any hints?

Comment: Open the .DPK package file. The Project Manager window should show a list of the files in the project, including Pnglang. Select that item in the list and delete it. If you get a warning about Pnglang being implicitly added to the project, don't ignore it. To resolve it, add vclimg150 to your package's "requires" list.

Comment: so I have a BPK file (not DPK) and there was a reference to vcljpg so I removed it thinking the whole image library (png, jpg) is contained in vclimg150?  It now compiles but won't install.  Complains about unit jconsts but cannot find any reference to jconsts in any source file.  See comments above about renaming pngimage to pngimage2.  I'd like to remove it but not sure how

Comment: OK, this ultimately helped me.  Huge Thank you Rob!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that as of Delphi 2009, Char, PChar, and String are Unicode, and store more than one byte per character.
You should not cast those pointers to bytes, and the compiler prevents you from assigning them if you cast the left side of an assignment to a byte.

This compiles:

```
procedure CopyInterlacedRGB8(const Pass: Byte; Dest: pAnsiChar); overload;
begin
  Byte(Dest^) := Pass;
end;
```

This doesn't:

```
procedure CopyInterlacedRGB8(const Pass: Byte; Dest: pChar); overload;
begin
  Byte(Dest^) := Pass;
end;
```

Instead of pChar, you should use pByte, which makes the code simpler:

```
procedure CopyInterlacedRGB8(const Pass: Byte; Dest: PByte); overload;
begin
  Dest^ := Pass;
end;
```

--jeroen

Comment: This looks promising.  I did change a lot of pChar to pAnsiChar but I did not change the function arguments.  I will try this and report back.

Comment: And how about the integer in:  Dest := pChar(Longint(Dest) + Col * 3);  ???????

Comment: @LincesMarques that would not get you a Byte value but a pointer to a 16-bit Char.

The repeat loop would still fail because it would increment the pointer by 16-bits, skipping part of the RGB bytes.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you're working with Gustavo Daud's TPngImage library.  You don't need that code in an external BPL because it's been included in the RTL since D2009.  Remove that unit from the BPL and you should be able to get at the updated version via the `PngImage` unit.

Comment: Not sure - you're probably correct.  It's IOCOMP's VCL tools we're using (http://www.iocomp.com/).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to remedy this?  I can't seem to find where pngimage is included in anything by hpp files  
grep pngimage *
iComponentEditorImageEditorPanel.hpp
#include <pngimage.hpp> // Pascal unit
Iocomp65.tds: grep: input lines truncated - result questionable
iVCLComponent.hpp
#include <pngimage.hpp> // Pascal unit
pngimage.hpp
// (DO NOT EDIT: machine generated header) 'pngimage.pas' rev: 22.00
PNGImage.pas
unit pngimage;
pngzlib.pas
{This unit links ZLIB to pngimage unit in order to implement  }

Comment: @Eric M: I'm sorry, I don't know anything about how packages and linking to .pas files are handled on the C++ Builder side.  Maybe you could ask that as a new question?

Comment: ok, since my last post, I simply renamed all copies of pngimage, pngzlib, and pnglang with pngimage2, pngzlib2, and pnglang2.  Everything still compiles fine but when I install, I get a conflict reported with JCONSTS and that it's in the same vclimg150 library.  I can't find jconsts referenced anywhere in the source tree.

Comment: @Eric M: Can't help you too much here, sorry.  I just happened to recognize the name `TChunkIDAT` from when I used to work with PngImage a lot back before it got added into the RTL.